# SQL query for null value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL function(`SplitString`) which returns string value by considering the separator(;) string to split the string. After getting the string one by one, I want to query in my table by using `WHERE` AND `IN` clause. But I have noticed it is not querying when the value is null. I am trying to figure out how to resolve it. My function(`SplitString`) takes 2 parameters. First the string and the separator. If I do the query, it returns empty string as NULL and other value.

```
SELECT [Value] FROM XYZ.SplitString(N';01e178bd-8f6c-488f-a0fa-81ffb598e569', ';') s
```

So from the above query it will return `NULL` AND `01e178bd-8f6c-488f-a0fa-81ffb598e569` :

Now I want to call a table with this query,

```
select * from Modeltable where ModelName IN (SELECT 
        [Value]
        FROM XYZ.SplitString(N';01e178bd-8f6c-488f-a0fa-81ffb598e569', ';') s)
```

In `Modeltable`, I have also null value which I want to fetch as well. What I understand that sql `IN` operator ignore the NULL value here. In this case, what should be the correct way to get data both for null and other string value?

Comment: What is this `ACDC.SplitString` and why don't you use the built in `STRING_SPLIT` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert the NULL values on *both sides* of the expression to something that will compare normally:

```
...
where coalesce(ModelName,'') IN (SELECT 
    coalesce([Value], '') ...
```

Note this breaks index use on the `ModelName` column, so it's better to plan ahead to not need to compare NULL at all when possible.

Comment: `ISNULL` would be better, as it tells the compiler that the value is not null. `COALESCE` is just seen as a `CASE` by the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `EXISTS` query and simple `AND` `OR` logic.

```sql
SELECT mt.*
FROM Modeltable mt
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM ACDC.SplitString(N';01e178bd-8f6c-488f-a0fa-81ffb598e569', ';') s
    WHERE s.Value = mt.ModelName
       OR s.Value IS NULL AND mt.ModelName IS NULL
);
```

In modern versions of SQL Server, you can use `STRING_SPLIT` and `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM`

```sql
SELECT mt.*
FROM Modeltable mt
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(N';01e178bd-8f6c-488f-a0fa-81ffb598e569', ';') s
    WHERE NULLIF(s.Value, '') IS NOT DISTINCT FROM mt.ModelName
);
```

Note that `STRING_SPLIT` returns `''` not `NULL` for an empty separator section, which is why you need to null it out before you compare it.